# Calculate mean value and do the minus

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I48BG.png)

I got a data frame as the image,

I am wondering how to get the mean of each day Numb from only Pos1,3,5,7 and then minus ctrl.

Take 2022/03/03 for instance: (92+17+51+79)/4 - 38.

My thought is to make two dataframe one including pos1~7 and get the average of it then concave it with ctrl.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

First replace `Numb` to missing value in [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) if position is `Ctrl`, so possible aggregate by `mean` and `last`, then subtract ctrl values:

```
df = (df.assign(Numb = df['Numb'].mask(df['Pos'].eq('Ctrl')))
        .groupby('Date').agg(ctrl = ('Numb','last'),
                             avg = ('Numb','mean'))
        .eval("avg-ctrl")
        .reset_index(name='ctrl'))
```

If possible `ctrl` value is not last, solution is:

```
df = (df.assign(Numb = df['Numb'].mask(df['Pos'].eq('Ctrl')),
                ctrl = df['Numb'].where(df['Pos'].eq('Ctrl')))
        .groupby('Date').agg(ctrl = ('Numb','last'),
                              avg = ('Numb','mean'))
        .eval("avg-ctrl")
        .reset_index(name='ctrl')
        )
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it's a lesson to me.
I think it should be"agg(ctrl = ('ctrl','last')"

Comment: @Shawn - then use `.reset_index(name='ctrl')` instead `.reset_index(name='difference')`

Answer (score 0):

you can use array functions, for example,

```py
dayMeans=[]
for i in range(0, numOfDays, 4): # i increments by 4
     dayMean = np.mean(Numb[i:i+4]) - Num[i+4]
     dayMeans.append(dayMean)
print(dayMeans)
```

we start at 0 index, and increment by 4 steps which are entries for each day. Appending results to the required array.